# How to create a wp admin page (for use in an ajax request)

Tags: wp-admin, ajax

How can I create a URL to an admin page (under /wp-admin/) that I'm not adding to the navigation? I want to use the URL for an ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, changed my google search terms and found my answer. :)

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins